Is a std:.span::iterator considered an iterator into the underlying container?
I have a situation where I want to copy data from a std::span into a std::vector using assign. In certain situations, the span can be on the target vector itself
The cppref states that (emphasis mine)

Replaces the contents with copies of those in the range [first, last). The behavior is undefined if either argument is an iterator into *this.

Now is this defined behavior?
std::vector<char> buffer;
size_t parse(std::span<char>);

void consume(std::span<char> data)
{
  // if there was some left over data in our buffer, append new data to buffer
  // and use the buffer as source for parsing
  if (!buffer.empty())
  {
    buffer.insert(buffer.end(), data.begin(), data.end());
    data = buffer;
  }

  // Parse data, may result in some left-over data for subsequent call
  size_t leftOver = parse(data);

  // Store non-consumed data in buffer
  // Note: data may be a view on buffer here!
  buffer.assign(data.begin() + leftOver, data.end()); // UB?
}


This is UB.
The point of this rule is that the vector might reallocate the buffer and/or move the elements around before dereferencing your iterator.
This is equally problematic for vector iterators, pointers into it, span iterators, etc.

I get the idea in general. However, the vector must have enough capacity (and size), as the iterators are into itself. I don't see a reason why the storage should be reallocated in that case. But I accept, that it is like this

@king_nak not just reallocations, but the order in which elements are copied. You might write to an element that you will later read from.

@Caleth I see. So this restriction gives the implementor more freedom.

I'm pretty sure that it would be undefined behaviour. The term "an iterator into container" isn't defined by the standard, but other places talk about specific iterators referring to an element of a container. The range indicated by data does refer to elements of buffer in the case you are worried about.

Yes, I figured it would be like that. C++ref uses the term "iterator into `this ", but that's not the standard...

@king_nak The standard does use roughly the same "a.assign(i, j) Preconditions: ... Neither i nor j are iterators into a."
